# Zoom an image bigger than screen resolution with react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using react-native-lightbox to zoom an image. I have a thumbnail and when this it's pressed, an image bigger than screen's resolution is loaded in order to make posible zooming without quality loss.

The problem came when lightbox is opened, the image is cropped to the screen size and I can't make it zoom to full size.

On Android is working well, so I asume that it's related to Retina Screen.

Any thoughts about this or do you know a component that allows me to accomplish this?

Here's the code:

```
    <Lightbox
        key={images.photo_id}
        activeProps={{
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            source: { uri: images.photo_sizes.full },
            style: { flex: 1, width: null, height: null }
        }}
    >
        <Image
            source={{ uri: images.photo_sizes.thumbnail }}
            style={ flex: 1, height: 200, width: null }
            resizeMode='cover'
        />
    </Lightbox>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrollview for implementing pinch zoom in ios, just put the image as below and set the maximumZoomScale and minimumZoomScale values. It will work only in ios.

```
<ScrollView maximumZoomScale={5} scrollEnabled={true} minimumZoomScale={1} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
 <Image
  style={{height:100, width: 300}}
  source={{ uri: "https://img0.gaadicdn.com/images/car-
          images/496x206/Lamborghini/Lamborghini-Huracan/Lamborghini-
          Huracan-Performante/047.jpg" 
        }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks @sooraj! If I do it this way, the zoomed image is getting blurry anyway. I've tried with a bigger image and the results are the same. I have a map with a legend on it and I need people can read it on zooming.

Comment: Could you please adjust the maximumZoomScale and try again